# How to include two object inside the same select on Linq MVC5

Tags: c#, linq

I do have a complex query to select a full object called Performance

The Performance relationship with others objects is:

- Performance has a list of Index
- Index has a list of SubIndex
- SubIndex has a list of Indicator
- Indicator has a list of Item

Item relationship with Spot and Measurement:

- Item has one Spot and one Measurement

The query below returns exactly what I want, but I would like to include the Spot and Measurement to the Item object.

```
return _context.Performance.Include(i => i.Indexes
                           .Select(s => s.SubIndexes
                           .Select(d => d.Indicators
                           .Select(t => t.Items))))
                           .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

I have tried the query below and it is returning the Measurement object. How to include the Spot object?

```
return _context.Performance.Include(i => i.Indexes
                           .Select(s => s.SubIndexes
                           .Select(d => d.Indicators
                           .Select(t => t.Items.Select(tm => tm.Measurement)))))
                           .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add second `Include` too;

```
return _context.Performance.Include(i => i.Indexes
       .Select(s => s.SubIndexes
       .Select(d => d.Indicators
       .Select(t => t.Items.Select(tm => tm.Measurement)))))
       .Include(i => i.Indexes
       .Select(s => s.SubIndexes
       .Select(d => d.Indicators
       .Select(t => t.Items.Select(tm => tm.Spot)))))
       .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not inform before. I am using MVC5. Is it possible in MVC5?

Comment: It worked using the second include (1st option). Is that the best way to query?

Comment: @shibata MVC5 is a web framework; it's not related to what you're doing here. This is Entity Framework, which is the technology allowing you to use LINQ to query an SQL database. When you install MVC5 it tends to come with EF as well, but the two are separate things.

Comment: @anaximander I got it, thank you. I have asked for MVC5 because the other example was related to MVC 6. I know linq and ef are separate things.

Comment: @shibata Fair enough - just thought I'd check; it's a common misconception in questions like this. You wouldn't believe how many questions we get asking how to use MVC to query SQL Server...